# When trying to read a variable from .env file, the variable gets truncated after = symbol

Tags: python-3.x, github, environment-variables, wsl-2

I am trying to retrieve a variable stored in the .env file using,

```
`import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
print(os.getenv("MONGODB_URI"))`
```

But it prints a part of it and ignores characters after (including) '=' of the particular string.

Note: I am using WSL2.

I tried pulling the same GitHub repo again and again once this issue happened. But this keeps frustrating me. I need to retrieve the full variable.

Comment: Give an example of the value of `MONGODB_URI`. Is it a single string, a JSON, ...? How are you storing it in the `.env` file?

Comment: @creme332      It is a string with special characters. 
"MONGODB_URI" = "mongodb+srv://codeuser-qa:somealphanum@clustername.mongodb.net/db_name?retryWrites=true&w=majority"

It truncates after 'retryWrites'.

Answer (score 0):

You are incorrectly storing `MONGODB_URI`. The key should not be within quotes. Here's how you can correctly store the variable in your `.env` file:

```
MONGODB_URI = mongodb+srv://codeuser-qa:somealphanum@clustername.mongodb.net/db_name?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

The output of your program then becomes:

```
mongodb+srv://codeuser-qa:somealphanum@clustername.mongodb.net/db_name?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

Note: I am using `python-dotenv==0.21.0` and Python 3.9.18.

If you are still facing issues:

- Ensure that you have a single `.env` file in the root of your project.
- Ensure that the key `MONGODB_URI` appears only once in your `.env` file.